# How to handle given extern function in C

Tags: c, gcc, system, system-calls

I've been given function called statPrint to handle printing of the system call stat(). The function is provided with another .o file. I'm getting errors when compiling my implementation with that function:

```
In function ‘main’:
statcall.c:9:19: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
statPrint(argv[1]*,sb*);
               ^
statcall.c:9:19: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘statPrint’
statcall.c:4:8: note: expected ‘struct stat *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stat’
extern statPrint(char*,struct stat*);
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
extern statPrint(char∗,struct stat∗);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct stat sb;
  stat(argv[1],&sb);   ///argv[1] contains input from the terminal/shell
  statPrint(argv[1]*,sb*);
}
```

I compile it with(libstat contains the external function):

```
gcc -o statcall statcall.c libstat.o
```

How do I get rid of the errors?

Comment: On this line: `extern statPrint(char∗,struct stat∗);`
Shouldn't statPrint have a return value?  Likely an `int` or a `void`?

Comment: That `∗` doesn't quite look like a `*`. Is that your actual source code???

Comment: Could you explain or give an example? I'm new to c and have never seen extern before. extern statPrint(char∗,struct stat∗) is how the teacher gave it to us. I thought I'm supposed to declare it like that and then use the statPrint function in main.

Comment: @barak Yes I don't know why the * got so wierd on stackoverflow.

Comment: I was actually trying to tell you that the compiler is not going to like it (if that's indeed what you have in your code).

Comment: Hang on a second, the teacher gave you this - `argv[1]*`??? You probably want to start looking for a different teacher (or a different school, with higher recruitment standards).

Comment: @abelenky do you mean like extern void statPrint(char*, struct stat*)? It is supposed to print out a string so I guess it should be void then.

Comment: @barak manos No no, what he gave us was this line extern statPrint(char∗,struct stat∗); and a .o file along with it and telling us to use it for printing the stat result. I'm just mainly confused how to use the function.

Comment: Exact same way you are using the `stat` function (one line above it).

Comment: Alright, I got it down to one error now. I fixed the pointers abit but is the char * parameter really valid in extern void statPrint(char *,struct *stat);
The error I got now is from the same line and is about struct *stat:


    error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token
    extern void statPrint(char *,struct *stat);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

```
statPrint(argv[1]*,sb*);
```

There's no valid syntax that ends with `*`.

---

I think you want:

```
statPrint(argv[1], &sb);
```

Recommend you read up on addresses of variables and pointers.

Comment: Yea needed to refresh my c syntax, was not used to it much from the beginning either. It worked after fixing all the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects `char *` please provide it

```
statPrint(argv[1],sb);
```

I really didn't get what is `argv[1]*`

Comment: Forgot to mention that i give a value(path) from the terminal/shell. Where do you mean I should provide the char?Don't i do that in main with statPrint(argv[1]*,sb*); ?

Comment: @nelthas can you please explain why are you adding the `*`?